# replace an IP@ by a URL using Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, centos6

I've just installed a webapp (sakai precisely) in a CentOs 6.2 server.
sakai is accessible via @ip:8080/portal, and I need to replace that adresse by a normal URL: www.exapmle.com/sakai

I've already replaced:

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
# ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
# DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
# ServerName dummy-host.example.com
# ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
# CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
#</VirtualHost>
```

by

```
<VirtualHost @ip:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@my_site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/cmcf
ServerName my_site.com
ErrorLog logs/my_site.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/my_site.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

(I also tried `<VirtualHost @ip:8080>` since my webapp is accessible via @ip:8080/portal but in vain)

but when I try to reach sakai from the browser, I get the 404 error:

```
**Not Found
The requested URL /portal was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at cmcf.men.gov.ma Port 80**
```

I also tried to make "/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.29"(where sakai is deployed) the DocumentRoot, (It is probably a very huge mistake, but it's the first time I manage apache, so...) and I've got the same 404 error.

I'll be pleased to get any of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Sakai Admin Guide](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/DOC/Sakai+Admin+Guide+-+Advanced+Tomcat++%28and+Apache%29+Configuration) has information on deploying your Tomcat app with Apache.

Basically, you will want to set up Apache as a reverse proxy of some sort, either using the basic reverse proxy configuration (mod_proxy) where you have something like this:

```
ProxyPass /sakai http://localhost:8080/portal
ProxyPassReverse /sakai http://localhost:8080/portal
```

where Tomcat is listening on localhost:8080.

The alternative is to set up Apache with mod_proxy_ajp, which will cause Apache to talk to Tomcat in a more native fashion.  For a simple setup, you can get away with using mod_proxy.  After that, you should get a better handle on how your webstack works, in terms of how the web server (Apache) and the application server (Tomcat) relate to each other.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and excuse me for the delay. Would you give some more explanations about the mod_proxy. I'm new to apache, so it's a little bit hard for me to apply what you've told me.  should I input the two commands you gave me in the httpdconf file? and where should I write the "url" that must replace the ip@?? Thank you

Comment: @ijlal I've updated my Answer to better reflect the paths that you had in your question.  Please look at the mod_proxy documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html for more information.  You should also be able to google for "apache mod_proxy examples" for more usage tips.